# Add arraylist to 2d arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I am having a list in the format

```
 ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList();
```

where I add and remove various elements in a loop. However, I need some structure where I can store the temporary lists so that I can access them later.

So for example, if I do System.out.print(list) it will return

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

then I need to call something like store.add(list)
and then if I add another element to the list - list.add(5) it becomes

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
then again
store.add(list)
```

and by calling System.out.print(store) it should return

```
[1,2,3,4]
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

In other words, store should be something like list within list?

Comment: You can always create a `List<List<Integer>>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you want to have **multiple versions** of the same list.

You can't get that by just having a List of List.

The list will store  only reference to the member lists stored inside it. So when you edit your list, all older versions will be edited as well. It's the same list behind the scene.

The correct way to use the `List<List<Integer>>` would be as follows.

```
List<List<Integer>> store = new ArrayList<>(); // Create storage for versions

List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
store.add(new ArrayList<>(list)); // Add list's copy to store.

list.add(5); // Edit it as you want.
store.add(new ArrayList<>(list)); // Add list's copy to store.

System.out.println(store); // Print all versions
```

**Output:**

> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

List in list creating like this: `List<List<Integer>> listInList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();`

Comment: Ok. And then how can I add say listInList[0] = mylist? listInList[1] = myList and so on. In other words, how can add in the various dimensions?

Comment: lidtInList.set(0,mylist);

Comment: @user3017335 You create `listOne [1, 2, 3, 4]`, and add it to `listInList.add(listOne)`. And you can get it `listInList.get(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

It is somewhat wasteful to store every new list, especially when the changes to the previous are very simple (e.g. additions and deletions at/from the end). You could come up with a strategy of keeping track of changes rather than storing the same information repeatedly.

First, you should decide which of the following is more important:

1. Have the list of lists readily available, at the expense of memory. This is desirable when you know you will need it very often and therefore cannot afford the overhead of generating it on-the-fly from history.
2. Use space efficiently, at the occasional cost of computing the list of lists from history. This is desirable when you make many changes and use the list of lists rarely.

The solutions already posted address 1., so here is a proposal for 2. (I will restrict the possible operations to adding and removing from the rear for the sake of brevity):

```
public enum Operation { ADD, REMOVE }
public class Modification {
  Operation operation;
  Integer element;
  public Modification(Operation operation, Integer element) {
    this.operation = operation; // could add some sanity checks (e.g. cannot remove from empty list)
    this.element = element;
  }
}

List<Integer> initialList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
List<Modification> history = new ArrayList<>();
history.add(new Modification(Operation.ADD, 5));
```

Then you can define a function to compute the list of lists that you need:

```
List<List<Integer>> getAllLists (List<Integer> initialList, List<Modification> history) {
  List<List<Integer>> allLists = new ArrayList<>();
  allLists.add(initialList);
  prevList = initialList;
  for (Modification modification : history) {
      prevList = new ArrayList<>(prevList);
      if (modification.operation == ADD) prevList.add(modification.element);
      else prevList.remove(prevList.size()-1);
      allLists.add(prevList);
  }
  return allLists;
}
```